# fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/BookShell527/BookShell527.github.io.git/': error setting certificate verify locations:

Tags: git, github

It fails when I used git command "git push -u origin master", message as below:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/BookShell527/BookShell527.github.io.git/': error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: D:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
```

any one got a solution?

Comment: you can ignore ssl error with `git config --global http.sslverify "false"` this is a temporary fix,

Answer (score 3):

Try this command

```
git config http.sslCAinfo "/D/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt"
```

Don't forget to make sure `ca-bundle.crt` file exist in the above defined path or not if the above file does not exist then the above command won't work

Command to make sure file exist or not

```
cd d/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

If the above command won't work for you then you can use this command to resolve your problem but it is just a temporary solution

```
git config --global http.sslverify "false"
```